# How would I display more of a scrollable view without increasing the height of the scrollbar track?

Tags: java, android, height, scrollbar

My goal is to show a view and display beyond the end of the scrollbar track, without increasing the height of said scrollbar track.

My current scrollbar implementation (the default scrollbar implementation) is set up such that the height of the view is kept within the bounds of the scrollbar track, which leaves this nasty cutoff and wasted space (basically anything beyond the top of the track gets cut off):

[image]

[image]

The goal is to have nothing look cut off like this at all and still scroll fully to the top and bottom, regardless of the height of the scrollbar's track. Here's an example I've seen:

[image]

Notice how there's nothing cut off when the contents of the view go beyond the top of the scrollbar track? That's what I'm aiming for; I want it so that regardless of the height of the scrollbar track, it will still display the view to the maximum upper and lower bounds of the screen I'm on, with the scrollbar still functioning normally. I have looked into the various views and how they implement their scrollbars, and I don't know if it's my lack of experience (Jr. Dev) or if I'm not looking in the right place, but I can't figure out a custom implementation for the scrollbar that would work the way I want it to. Any and all help would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: I had this problem too, set `cliptochildren=false` and `clippadding=false` to all parents of scrollbar and then see magic.

Comment: @EAS I added those to the parents and it didn't improve anything that I could see, unfortunately.